# Conditionally formatting the minimum value in a row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

My goal is to apply conditional formatting to the minimum value in a row of a Google Spreadsheets.

Under Conditional Formatting I've tried using "Custom Formula Is" `=MIN(D3:L3)`.

The result was that Conditional Formatting was applied to D3:L3 (the entire row).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sooo close (I think!). Please try:

```
=D3=min($D3:$L3)
```

`=min(D3:L3)` returns a value but CF needs a TRUE to trigger. So we check "the current cell" (D3) to see whether its value matches that of the minimum in the range D3:L3. If it does we trigger the formatting.

I say "the current cell" because quite which that is depends on the `Range:` selection. Here it is the same as that from which the minimum value is selected (ie D3:L3). CF has a kind of rastering feature, equivalent to checking whether to trigger the first cell in the `Range:` (and if TRUE, doing so) then automatically stepping on the E3, F3 cell (and if TRUE, doing so) etc until reaching the end of `Range:`.

(I have no idea what the actual sequence is but since all done with one click don't see that matters much.)

Without anchors (the `$`s in $D3:$L3) the minimum range also would auto adjust during the process, so D3 would be tested against D3:L3 but E3 against E3:M3, and so on.  (This particular question, where the MIN range and `Range:` are the same, may not however be the most suitable one for explaining the anchors!)

Comment: Wow, that produced exactly the desired result, thank you!  Next I'm going to figure out how the first part of the formula (=D3) works.