# Minimum value across multiple rows, conditionally formatted

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need help understanding how the MIN formula mixes with conditional formatting, cause I can't wrap my head around it.

Here's specific situation:
[image]

I've successfully got formatting for minimum across *just the row* (bold, blue) -- it uses the strange "Is equal to" with `=min(55:55)` .

Anyway, now I also want the minimum across all those rows to be red fill.  Shown in image are a bunch of erroneously filled numbers.  In this case just the cell H64, with value 54, should be filled red.

I've tried different variations of "Is equal to" , "Less than or equal to" `=min(F54:M67)` , to no avail.

How to get minimum value across multiple rows to be conditionally formatted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally formatting the minimum value in a row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69120/conditionally-formatting-the-minimum-value-in-a-row)

Comment: @Tedinoz Not a duplicate: min in `rectangular range` vs. min in `row`, use `compare` vs. use `custom formula`.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you. You're absolutely right. I misread the question :(

Comment: @Tedinoz, I squeaked by previously and managed to get a relative minimum coloring going for a single row.  I guess I wanted this behavior previously, cause it was easier to to have it auto-color subsequent rows, as long as the formatted range was big enough.  Now, for this current question, I absolutely did need the absolute anchors, and that helps explain!

Comment: @icy I find it _disappointing_ that the conditional formatting documentation doesn't deal with the various permutations of cell references. Even when one has a very good understanding of absolute/relative referencing, the implications for conditional formatting are far from intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Is equal to` `=min($F$54:$M$67)`.

See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).

Comment: Regarding the explanation of cell references, from [How do I write a good answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) "Links to external resources are encouraged, but... always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: ty, the absolute ref did it!